# How to correctly manage references returned by g_dbus_interface_get_object()

Tags: linux, memory-management, gdbus, udisks

I have an application in which I'm using UDisks to handle some drives and partitions.  In my application I have a situation where I have a pointer to a `UDisksDrive` that I need to convert to a `UDisksObject` pointer through which I can access other interfaces later.  I'm quite unclear as to what objects I should unreference and when. In one function, I currently do:

```
    UDisksDrive* drive = udisks_client_get_drive_for_block(client, block);
    if(drive == NULL) {
        g_object_unref(block);
        return NULL;
    }

    UDisksObject* driveObject = (UDisksObject*) g_dbus_interface_get_object(G_DBUS_INTERFACE(drive));
    g_object_unref(drive);
    return driveObject;
```

But I don't know if this is right.  It works, but I know that might not necessarily mean anything.  The gdbus documentation for `g_dbus_interface_get_object()` reads like I shouldn't be unreferencing the returned `driveObject` variable when the receiving function is done with it, but I'm not sure.  I feel like I should be unreferencing `block` before the functions returns too, but I don't know why I'm not.  This is a project I only get time to work on here and there, and I feel like perhaps I'd tried it and it caused a crash or exception.

Most of my other code involving UDisks is pretty straight-forward.  I `_get_` something, use it, and unreference it.  It's this stuff that involves interface swapping that I'm a little fuzzy on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time to think, research, and a brief chat on IRC has resulted in the following:

Yes, I definitely need to free (unreference) `block` before the function returns.  Also, `g_dbus_interface_get_object()` is the wrong function for this situation.  Because I don't care about `drive` and just want to returns `driveObject`, I need to use `g_dbus_interface_dup_object()` instead, which allows the returned pointer to own it's own reference.  That makes it so that the caller can free `driveObject` safely when it's done with it.  So the updated code snippet looks like this:

```
    UDisksDrive* drive = udisks_client_get_drive_for_block(client, block);
    if(drive == NULL) {
        g_object_unref(blockObject);
        g_object_unref(block);
        return NULL;
    }

    UDisksObject* driveObject = (UDisksObject*) g_dbus_interface_dup_object(G_DBUS_INTERFACE(drive));
    g_object_unref(block);
    g_object_unref(drive);
    g_object_unref(blockObject);

    return driveObject;
```